# android studio 3.3 clang-tidy

Tags: android, android-studio, c++14, clang-tidy

Yesterday, Google updated Android Studio to version 3.3 and there it was possible to use a static analyzer for libraries supporting C ++. So, how exactly to use it? I include in:

> Preferences->Editor->Inspections->General->Clang-tidy

(Use IDE setting )
but nothing else. If you try through the terminal for the android studio - Then you need to write all the dependencies manually, which is not correct, apparently. And my question is - how in uses cland-tidy for Android studio version 3.3?

I would be grateful for any help and support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Android Studio main menu: Analyze -> Run Inspection By Name... 
select 'Clang-Tidy', "Run 'Clang-Tidy'" dialog box will appear. Set up needed options and click 'OK'. In the end of the inspection results will be displayed in "Inspection Results" bottom tab.